# jQuery - using $(this) in custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create a custom function that unbinds and then binds an event. It looks like this:

```
App.bindEvent = function(selector, eventType, eventHandler) {
    $(selector).unbind(eventType);
    $(selector).bind(eventType, function(event) {
        eventHandler(event);
    });
};
```

However, the problem I am facing is that I cannot use the this keyword to reference the DOM element that was clicked. For example, I cannot do this:

```
App.bindEvent("#my-element", "click", function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr("data-my-id");
});
```

How would I go about getting the this keyword to point to the clicked DOM element like it does in jQuery.bind()?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
eventHandler(event);
```

To:

```
eventHandler.call(this, event);
```

That'll change the "scope" of your function to be the same as the scope of the original "bind" call.

Answer (score 2):

How about this instead:

```
App.bindEvent = function(selector, eventType, eventHandler) {
    var element = this;

    $(selector).unbind(eventType);
    $(selector).bind(eventType, function(event) {
        eventHandler.call(element, event);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the handler in the context of the object:

```
eventHandler.call(this, event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to refer to

```
event.target
```

For example:

```
App.bindEvent("#my-element", "click", function(event) {
    var myId = $(event.target).attr("data-my-id");
});
```

check out [jquery's event documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)